# Using nested routes Rails 3 without actually allowing access to the parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-routes

I'm using Rails 3 and I have two models EquipmentGroup and Reservation. I want reservations to be a nested resource of equipment groups so that I can access them with URLs like:

```
/equipment_groups/:equipment_group_id/reservations/:id
```

However, I don't want to create routes for the equipment groups. I can achieve this through the following, but it seems like a hack:

```
resources :equipment_groups, :only => [] do
  resources :reservations
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? I can't seem to find an answer easily in the documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Your approach - it's a standard approach, there is nothing better.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways of doing this. One way is what you've done above. However, it seems like you have no need to expose the equipment groups controller or any of its actions, so the following should do just fine:

```
scope "/equipment_groups" do
    resources :reservations
end
```

The `scope` block will append "/equipment_groups" to every route in it. This will essentially "fake" a nested route.

Comment: By using `scope` instead of `resources`, you lose some of the magic of url generation. For instance, `equipment_group_reservation_path(@equipment_group, @reservation)` will not work. I prefer the solution suggested in the question itself, and I do not consider it a hack.

Comment: This will not work! with this approach you will have route which is similar but without parent ID and without any helpers for generating routes.